# as3-fb-api: how is it possible to have an accesstoken BEFORE Facebook.init()

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

the Facebook.init method of the as3-facebook-api (for flash) allows for an optional accesstoken parameter.

But the whole point of the .init(...) method is to, well, init everything ... accesstokens are a byproduct of the init phase.

So how is it possible to even have an accesstoken in the first place.

(Please do not respond with a rhetorical answer ... I am looking for a app-practical answer ... thanks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access token is valid for a specific amount of time, so technically you could reuse it. That, or you could have connected to Facebook using another language and have a token from that (more common than you'd think)

**Edit 24/05/2012**

Ok, After running some tests, and looking at the code in the Facebook AS3, this is what I have:

- You're right in that you have to call Facebook.init() first, before you do anything. Otherwise, you just get errors everywhere
- Passing an accessToken won't do anything *unless* you also pass and options `Object` with `status = false` (so your `init()` call becomes `Facebook.init( APP_ID, this._onInit, {status:false}, myAccessToken);`)
- Basically what it does is inits the lib, but doesn't call the `getLoginStatus()` external event, so you're saving a few calls and your program starts quicker - that's about it as far as I could tell.
- If you don't care about the lib, and you have an access token, technically you could bypass `init()` altogether, and just append `?access_token=[myToken]` to the end of your urls when you call `api()` (e.g. `Facebook.api( "/me?access_token=" + myAccessToken, this._onInfo );`) - or skip the lib entirely, and just make a `URLLoader` request to the url

A simple example showing all of this. Create your app as normal, substitute your app id, and connect normally. It'll trace out your uid and access token. Copy the token, launch the app again, and paste the token into the input area. It'll now use this when you `init()` again.

```
package 
{
    import com.facebook.graph.data.FacebookAuthResponse;
    import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

    /**
     * Test facebook connect, showing the init() call with and without an access token. Make a normal
     * connection, then copy the access token, and reload. paste your token into the input area to use
     * it for the init() call
     * @author Damian Connolly
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private static const APP_ID:String = "[SET_YOUR_APP_ID]";

        private var m_tf:TextFormat     = new TextFormat( "Trebuchet Ms", 9 );
        private var m_input:TextField   = null; // for adding the token
        private var m_log:TextField     = null; // for logging our messages

        public function Main():void 
        {
            // create our input
            this.m_input                    = new TextField;
            this.m_input.defaultTextFormat  = this.m_tf;
            this.m_input.border             = true;
            this.m_input.background         = true;
            this.m_input.type               = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            this.m_input.text               = " ";
            this.m_input.width              = 700.0;
            this.m_input.height             = this.m_input.textHeight + 4.0;
            this.m_input.text               = "";
            this.m_input.x = this.m_input.y = 10.0;
            this.addChild( this.m_input );

            // log and add our mouse listeners
            this._log( "Press [SPACE] to init facebook connection, [CTRL] to login, [SHIFT] to get data" );
            this._log( "Copy a pre-existing token into the textfield above to use it in the init() call" );
            this.stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, this._onKeyDown );
        }

        // keyboard listener
        private function _onKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
        {
            if ( e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE )
                this._init();
            else if ( e.keyCode == Keyboard.CONTROL )
                this._login();
            else if ( e.keyCode == Keyboard.SHIFT )
                this._getData();
        }

        // init our facebook api
        private function _init():void
        {
            // use our token if we have one
            var token:String = ( this.m_input.text != "" ) ? this.m_input.text : null;

            this._log( "---------- Initing facebook with token '" + token + "'" );
            if ( token == null )
                Facebook.init( Main.APP_ID, this._onInit );
            else
            {
                var options:* = { status:false };
                Facebook.init( Main.APP_ID, this._onInit, options, token );
            }
        }

        // callback for init
        private function _onInit( success:*, fail:* ):void
        {
            this._log( "Callback for init 2! success: " + success + ", fail: " + fail );
            this._log( "Success: " + getQualifiedClassName( success ) );
            this._log( "Fail: " + getQualifiedClassName( fail ) );

            var response:FacebookAuthResponse = success as FacebookAuthResponse;
            if ( response != null )
                this._log( "UID: " + response.uid + ", access token: " + response.accessToken );

            this._log( ( success != null ) ? "Logged in" : "Not logged in" );
        }

        // logs into the app if we need to
        private function _login():void
        {
            this._log( "---------- Logging in" );
            Facebook.login( this._onLogin );
        }

        // callback for the login
        private function _onLogin( success:*, fail:* ):void
        {
            this._log( "Callback for _onLogin! success: " + success + ", fail: " + fail );
            this._log( "Success: " + getQualifiedClassName( success ) );
            this._log( "Fail: " + getQualifiedClassName( fail ) );

            var response:FacebookAuthResponse = success as FacebookAuthResponse;
            if ( response != null )
                this._log( "UID: " + response.uid + ", access token: " + response.accessToken );
        }

        // gets our data
        private function _getData():void
        {
            this._log( "---------- getting data with url '/me'" );
            Facebook.api( "/me", this._onGetData );
        }

        // callback for our data
        private function _onGetData( success:*, fail:* ):void
        {
            this._log( "Callback for _onLogin! success: " + success + ", fail: " + fail );
            this._log( "Success: " + getQualifiedClassName( success ) );
            for ( var key:* in success )
                this._log( "  key '" + key + "' = " + success[key] );

            this._log( "Fail: " + getQualifiedClassName( fail ) );
        }

        // logs a message to the console and our textfield
        private function _log( msg:String ):void
        {
            // create our log if needed
            if ( this.m_log == null )
            {
                this.m_log                      = new TextField;
                this.m_log.defaultTextFormat    = this.m_tf;
                this.m_log.border               = true;
                this.m_log.background           = true;
                this.m_log.width                = 700.0;
                this.m_log.height               = 200.0;
                this.m_log.x                    = this.m_input.x;
                this.m_log.y                    = this.m_input.y + this.m_input.height + 5.0;
                this.m_log.wordWrap             = true;
                this.addChild( this.m_log );
            }
            trace( msg );
            this.m_log.appendText( msg + "\n" );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: does there exist some phase that precedes the **Facebook.init(...)** phase? I thought that that _WAS_ the first phase.

... ... And even if you had an access token from a previous session/cookie, you would still need to init the facebook .as/.js _first_ in order to even get the token, right?

Comment: could I ask that maybe you give a _very casual_ example of an app that  queries for an existing accesstoken **prior** to the _Facebook.init(...)_ phase, without depending on the Facebook.init(...) phase at all.

Comment: np, i'll see if i can work up a quick example tomorrow evening

Comment: just added an example. after testing it, it can save you a bit of init time, but from what i've seen, you get the same token back even if you `init()` normally each time, so it's up to you if you want to use it. You can store your access token and expires date in a shared object or db etc

Comment: it appears that in your example you must init ONCE to get an access token, then after that you can use that token to init again if you wish, thus according to this example there is NOT a way to have an access token BEFORE your first Facebook.init(...).

So that implies to me that facebook anticipates that developers will build apps that use the .init method multiple times?? strange..

nice example, btw.

Comment: I would maybe add another edit to your post to mention, verbatim, that there is not a way to have an access token at the moment of Facebook.init(...) UNLESS you have acquired it through some non-linear way, such as making multiple .init calls (why would an app do that?) or possibly using php call to get it before making as3 Facebook.init(...) call.

Comment: It's not uncommon for an app to use multiple sdk's. Take for example, a flash game. You can have the init() though js (maybe showing popups), flash (in-game stuff), and backend (java, php - buying things) etc. You can pass this token to the swf on startup. Or, if you have a token (or offline access), it's valid for a certain amount of time, so if you save it in a lso, you can reuse it. Long story short, it's possible to have a token before `init()` :)